# Disable touch action on parent element while keeping on child element in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mobile

I have implemented web page consisted of several layers. It is done using React and ant design.
I used two Ant design Drawers; one from left placement, the other one inside former drawer from bottom placement. The picky issue is when I touch and scroll on top Drawer, the underneath layer is also moving.
So my question is how to disable touch action on underneath layer while enabling touch action on top layer in react, or javascript or css.
Thank you in advance.

My code looks like

```
<div className="bottomDrawer">
  <div className="topDrawer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not enough infos for us to help you. lease provide a small reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Hi, Dominik. Thank you for your attention. If I touch and move on the top Drawer, the same touch action applies to its parent element. So my question is how to disable touch action on parent element while keeping it on child element. Thank you again.